# how to loop through "ul" children using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a UL identified by class which is stored in a different var.
Inside this UL i have a few li and inside each li i have an  tag.
I wish to loop through the ul and alert each  id (just to see that i managed to access all a in the ul) - for this example i want to alert "b" and then "ac".

```
<ul class="par1">
     <li><a href="welcome.html" id="b"  target="tar">test</a></li>
     <li><a href="Register_client.aspx" id="ac" target="tar">test1</a></li>
</ul>
```

i tried this : (element is the var which contains the class name)

```
$('.' + element).children().each(alert(this));
```

which gave me the url of each link i clicked but not for both (in this example) links.

what am i doing wrong here? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works.

```
$('.' + element + ' > li').find("a").each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$('.' + element).find('a').each(function(){ //Iterate anchor
    alert($(this).text()); //Use .text() to get its text
    alert(this.id); //Alert ID
});
```

Comment: this works just great, but how can i get the <a> attributes and not the text?

Comment: @YushN might be you want this `alert($(this).attr("href"))`

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$('.' + element + ' a').each(function() {
   alert(this.id);    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6wc2d1y/)

Comment: Will this not select the `<li>` elements?.  Nevermind, I see you edited your post.

Comment: @user1032531: I originally understood that he wanted to iterate through multiple ul that were child of `element`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.par1').find('li').each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```